# How to get state of Reactstrap's CustomInput Switch component, and how to map switches from an array?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, frontend, reactstrap

```
        <FormGroup>
          <div>
            {this.props.diseases.map((disease, index) => (
              <FormGroup>
                <CustomInput
                  type="switch" 
                  id="exampleCustomSwitch"
                  key={disease}
                  disease={disease}
                  onClick={(disease) => this.props.toggle(disease)}
                  label={disease}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            ))
            }
          </div>
        </FormGroup>
```

1. I want to be able to find out the state of the switch, whether it's switched on or off. Not sure how I'm able to do that? Am I to pass in a default value of some sort with 0 as off and 1 as on?
2. Presently, the switches are mapping appropriately from the array, but switching on or off only works for the first switch. So, if I click on any of the other switches, for some reason the first switch toggles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For point #1,yYou can use `e.target.checked` to check the true/false status for a particular `CustomInput`; Check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vjtclu) to see it work

For point #2 If you share your existing code, it will be easier to help with your specific scenario

relevant **js**:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "World to React",
      log: []
    };
    this.customInputSwitched.bind(this);
  }

  customInputSwitched(buttonName, e) {
    let newStr = `we received ${e.target.checked} for ${buttonName}...`;
    console.log(newStr);
    let newLog = [...this.state.log, newStr];
    this.setState({ log: newLog });
  }

  render() {
    var testName = "modal for testing - click here";
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="exampleCheckbox">Switches</Label>
            <div>
              <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id="exampleCustomSwitch"
                name="customSwitch"
                label="Turn on this custom switch"
                onChange={this.customInputSwitched.bind(this, "button1")}
              />
              <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id="exampleCustomSwitch2"
                name="customSwitch"
                label="Or this one"
                onChange={this.customInputSwitched.bind(this, "button2")}
              />
              <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id="exampleCustomSwitch3"
                label="But not this disabled one"
                disabled
              />
              <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id="exampleCustomSwitch4"
                label="Can't click this label to turn on!"
                htmlFor="exampleCustomSwitch4_X"
                disabled
              />
            </div>
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
        {this.state.log}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE #1**: In light of questioner's comment below

Few issues in your code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rcqlwq

- you have to instantiate Log in the state in the contstructor
- the `customInputSwitched` function should pass the argument of the particular button, not a hard-coded 'button1' - so we add the index number of the disease
- the ID of all the buttons can't be the same 'exampleCustomSwitch', so we just add the index number to ID
- best practice in mapping as array is to include an index also, which has benefits (as shown in the next 2 points)

**relevant working JS** for your code/stackblitz:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      diseases: [
  "Normal",
  "Over inflated lungs",
  "Pneumonia",
  "Pneumothorax",
  "Congestive cardiac failure",
  "Consolidation",
  "Hilar enlargement",
  "Medical device",
  "Effusion"
],
log: []
    };
    this.customInputSwitched.bind(this);
  }

  customInputSwitched(buttonName, e) {
    let newStr = `we received ${e.target.checked} for ${buttonName}...`;
    console.log(newStr);
    let newLog = [...this.state.log, newStr];
    this.setState({ log: newLog });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="exampleCheckbox">Switches</Label>
            {this.state.diseases.map((disease, index) => {
              //console.log(disease, index);
              let idName = "exampleCustomSwitch"+index;

              return (
              <div key={index}>
                <CustomInput
                type="switch"
                id={idName}
                name="customSwitch"
                label={disease}
                onChange={this.customInputSwitched.bind(this, "button"+index)}
              />
              </div>
              );
            }

            )}
          </FormGroup>
        </Form>
        {this.state.log}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it also tells me some error about concat on StackBlitz, but the error is replicated regardless, you can see for a split second that if you try to switch any of the switches that isn't the first one, it switches the first one for some reason: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rcqlwq

Comment: Hi @BlahZayBlahZay, updated the answer in light of your shared stackblitz... working code also available at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-djmwut

Comment: Follow-up question: What is an elegant way so that, if I click on a button, all the toggled switches reset to un-switched? Would this involve re-rendering the component or passing some kind of parameter?